# Find a recursive formula for $J_n = \int_0^{\infty} x^{2n+1}e^{-x^2} \, \mathrm{d}x$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals, recursion

> Given
>   $$ J_n\stackrel{\text{def}}{=}\int_{0}^{+\infty}x^{2n+1}e^{-x^2}\,dx $$
>   compute $J_0$, $J_1$ and find a recursion formula for $J_n$.

I have computed $J_0$ and $J_1$ but I am clueless about the recursion formula, may I ask for some help? By integration by parts I got
$$ J_0 = \frac{1}{2},\qquad J_1 = \frac{1}{2}.$$

Comment: I edited, hope its readable now

Answer (score 4):

Alternatively write $$\begin{align}J_n &= -\frac{1}{2}\int_0^{\infty}-2xe^{-x^2}x^{2n} \, \mathrm{d}x\\ & = -\frac{1}{2}\bigg[x^{2n}e^{-x^2}\bigg]_0^{\infty} + \frac{1}{2}\int_0^{\infty} 2nx^{2n-1}e^{-x^2} \, \mathrm{d}x  \\ & = nJ_{n-1}\end{align}$$

using IBP with $u = x^{2n}$ and $\mathrm{d}v = -2xe^{-x^2} \implies v=e^{-x^2}$.

Comment: thanks! the trick with multiplying 1/2 makes the IBP way easier

Answer (score 3):

By setting $x=\sqrt{z}$ we have

$$ J_n = \frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{+\infty} z^{n} e^{-z}\,dz = \frac{n!}{2} $$
due to the integral definition of the $\Gamma$ function. In particular

$$ J_{n+1} = (n+1)\,J_n$$
holds by integration by parts.

Comment: wow the gamma function makes this really easy!